# javascript function DOM event listener using "this"

Tags: javascript, dom

I want my event listener function, isTwoCards, to grab information from the object that is calling it. this code gives me element.getAttribute is not a function

```
var gameboard = document.getElementById('game-board');
var cards = ['queen', 'queen', 'king', 'king'];
var cardsInPlay = [];

var isTwoCards = function(element){
    cardsInPlay.push(element.getAttribute('data-card'));
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2){
        isMatch(cardsInPlay);
        cardsInPlay = [];
    }
}
var createBoard = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){
        cardDiv = document.createElement('div');
        cardDiv.setAttribute('class', 'card');
        cardDiv.setAttribute('data-card', cards[i]);
        cardDiv.setAttribute('id', i);
        cardDiv.addEventListener('click', isTwoCards(this));
        gameboard.appendChild(cardDiv);
    }
}
createBoard()
```

Comment: `cardDiv.addEventListener('click', isTwoCards);` then in `isTwoCards()` do: `cardsInPlay.push(this.getAttribute('data-card'));`

Comment: You don't need to pass this as an argument (which also doesn't work). Replace `isTwoCards(this)` with `isTwoCards`, and `element.getAttribute('data-card')` with `this.getAttribute('data-card')`

Comment: `addEventListener('click', isTwoCards(this))` <--- This is calling the `isTwoCards` function, not adding it as a listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as mentioned before is that you are executing the function and not just passing it as an argument. Take a look at this example:

```
someDomElement.addEventListener('click', function() { })
```

Let's store that function in a variable and then pass it as an argument.

```
const myFunction = function() { }
someDomElement.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
```

See, I just passed the function stored in a variable as an argument. Now what you are doing is executing the function:

```
const myFunction = function() { }
someDomElement.addEventListener('click', myFunction())
```

That is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You run `isTwoCards` right away instead of assigning it as a callback. From what I can see what you need is to assign `isTwoCards` (and not its result!) as a callback - i.e. `cardDiv.addEventListener('click', isTwoCards)`. You should also use `this.getAttribute('data-card')` instead `element`. `this` is assigned to the element when function is fired as a callback and not when the callback is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually attaching `undefined` as the listener because it is executing the function and its return value is `undefined`.

You can fix this by creating a closure/simply returning a new function:

```
var isTwoCards = function(element){
  return function () {
    cardsInPlay.push(element.getAttribute('data-card'));
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2){
        isMatch(cardsInPlay);
        cardsInPlay = [];
    }
  };
}
```

You can also simply access `this` inside the listener to access the element that the event listener is bound to:

```
var isTwoCards = function(){
    var element = this;
    cardsInPlay.push(element.getAttribute('data-card'));
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2){
        isMatch(cardsInPlay);
        cardsInPlay = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't fix problem with calling a function instead of adding it as a listener. `cardDiv.addEventListener('click', isTwoCards(this));`

Comment: That is only a problem if `isTwoCards` does not return a function.

Comment: That is very true.